# how to retrieve the data from ms-sql server directory

Tags: sql-server

I have MS SQL server and recently my system get formatted.
Now I have only MS SQL directory. 
I tried to retrieve the data from the directory.
Please help me to how can i retrieve the database from this MS SQL directory?
I have database.MDF and database.LDF files.

Comment: Are the database still in the directory? If so, re-installed SQL Server and the reattach the databases. If they aren't there anymore, they are gone, for good.

Comment: you may refer to following on how to attach a database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017